# Openshift deployment strategy delegation through sa

Tags: openshift, okd

We have a tool that provisions the ci/cd workflow for all the teams in our company. As part of the tool chain provisioning we are also creating openshift project automatically.
I am trying to figure out a best automated athorization strategy for invidual team's deployment process

Here is what we are doing currently

```
Create a project (eg: testproject)
Create a service account(oc create sa testuser)
Add user to admin role for the project (oc policy add-role-to-user admin system:serviceaccount:testproject:testuser)
```

Now we retrieve the api token for sa account testuser 
    oc describe sa testuser (Get the predefined token of testuser)
    oc describe secret testuser-token-gd9sl (Get the session token)

Through describe secret command, we can retrieve the api token. We give these api tokens to individual teams.

```
oc login https://192.219.152.34.nip.io –token=adfasdfsdaf23423  

Teams Once logged in as using their token , they are able to peform any api oerations in the scope of testproject. 
eg: oc create -f testproject-deploymentconfig.yml
    oc create -f testproject-service.yml
```

Is this approach correct ? does it have any draw back ? is there a better approach to this? Can anyone suggest

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion which become better your automatic object processing (I hope it).

Above process (create `project` and `sa`) should be executed when new `project` is created, then you can use the task via `project template` - [Modifying the Template for New Projects](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/admin_guide/managing_projects.html#modifying-the-template-for-new-projects).

For instance, you can include your `serviceaccount yaml` definition in the template.

Comment: Except that project template applies to every project created in the cluster, which isn't necessarily convenient.

Answer (score 0):

We do it mostly the same way.
Within a Jenkins pipeline we create a project via a template yaml file.
This includes project metadata and annotations, an named user (LDAP login of the requester) associated as admin and some predefined pull secrets.
Login to Openshift is secured by Keycloak with MFA. And afterwards the admin account himself can edit membership and add serviceaccounts as needed.

We also didn't modify the default project template.